Difference between tensile strength and work of fracture
Can someone please explain the difference between tensile strength and work of fracture of a material? What is the need to know the work of fracture if we already knew the tensile strength of the material? I couldn't understand it intuitively. An explanation would be a good help.

The tensile strength corresponds to a height (often the maximum height) of a stress–strain curve. The work of fracture could be defined as the area under the stress–strain curve. (If you’re using different definitions, please provide these definitions.) Not only is one not exactly predictive of the other, but they don’t even have the same units. Both provide independent information about how a material responds to loading.
